# How does this default template struct assignment work?

Tags: c++

I have been digging into some embedded C++ firmware used by DaveJone's (eevblog) uSupply project

https://gitlab.com/eevblog/usupply-firmware.

There is common pattern of code that I just can't quite wrap my head around what is happening.

For example:
In the file "RegistersRCC.hpp" there is a template struct:

```
template <std::size_t A>
struct CR : public General::u32_reg<A>
{
    using base_t = General::u32_reg<A>;
    using base_t::base_t;

    //PLL register bits
    auto PLLRDY () { return base_t::template Actual<RCC_CR_PLLRDY>(); }
    auto PLLON  () { return base_t::template Actual<RCC_CR_PLLON>(); }

    //PLL Management functions
    void EnablePLL() noexcept
    {
        if ( not PLLON().Get() )
        {
            PLLON() = true;
            while ( not PLLRDY().Get() );
        }
    }
    void DisablePLL() noexcept
    {
        if ( PLLON().Get() )
        {
            PLLON() = false;
            while ( PLLRDY().Get() );
        }
    }

    //Enable clock security
    auto CSSON  () { return base_t::template Actual<RCC_CR_CSSON>(); }

    //High speed external oscillator bits
    auto HSEBYP () { return base_t::template Actual<RCC_CR_HSEBYP>(); }
    auto HSERDY () { return base_t::template Actual<RCC_CR_HSERDY>(); }
    auto HSEON  () { return base_t::template Actual<RCC_CR_HSEON>(); }

    //HSE Management functions
    void EnableHSE()
    {
        if ( not HSEON().Get() )
        {
            HSEON() = true;                 //Enable the clock
            while( not HSERDY().Get() );    //Wait for it to stable
        }
    }
    void DisableHSE()
    {
        if ( HSEON().Get() )
        {
            HSEON() = false;            //Disable the clock
            while( HSERDY().Get() );    //Wait for it to disable
        }
    }
    void ConnectHSE()
    {
        HSEBYP() = false;   //Connect it to system
    }
    void BypassHSE()
    {
        HSEBYP() = true;    //Disconnect it to system
    }

    //High speed internal oscillator bits
    auto HSICAL () { return base_t::template Actual<RCC_CR_HSICAL>(); }
    auto HSITRIM() { return base_t::template Actual<RCC_CR_HSITRIM>(); }
    auto HSIRDY () { return base_t::template Actual<RCC_CR_HSIRDY>(); }
    auto HSION  () { return base_t::template Actual<RCC_CR_HSION>(); }

    //HSI Management functions, No calibration provided
    // these chips are factory calibrated
    void EnableHSI()
    {
        if (not HSION().Get())
        {
            HSION() = true;
            while (!HSIRDY());
        }
    }
    void DisableHSI()
    {
        if ( HSION().Get() )
        {
            HSION() = false;
            while (HSIRDY());
        }
    }
};
```

This struct exists in the namespace:

```
namespace Peripherals::RCCGeneral
{

}
```

Within the same namespace/header file there is this "Default"

```
CR() -> CR<RCC_BASE + offsetof(RCC_TypeDef, CR)>;
```

I think this is where my gap in understanding lies. **What is happening here?** Specifically with the lvalue and arrow operator, and why this is located within the header.

Within the files that utilize the RCCRegisters you see usages like:

```
CR{}.DisablePLL();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called class template argument deduction(CTAD) which allows writing deduction guides to the compiler about how to deduce the template arguments from constructor calls.

It is a handy C++17 addition that saves on typing:

```
std::vector x{1.,2.,3.} //deduces std::vector<double>
```

C++14 and older requires to explicitly write `std::vector<double>` which gets tedious and too verbose for some more complex examples.

In this case, the guide

```
CR() -> CR<RCC_BASE + offsetof(RCC_TypeDef, CR)>;
```

specifies that the default constructor should deduce `A` template parameter to `RCC_BASE + offsetof(RCC_TypeDef, CR)`.

The same *could* have been achieved by simply using a default template argument:

```
template <std::size_t A = default_value>
struct CR : public General::u32_reg<A>{ ... };
```

<s>But here comes the catch, `offsetof(RCC_TypeDef, CR)` is not valid here because at this line, `CR` doesn't exist yet.</s>

So my assumption is this a fix around this limitation to allow making the default value depend on the class definition itself, quite clever I think.

Comment: Cool that makes a lot of sense when you write it the alternative way you show. offsetof(RCC_TypeDef, CR) I believe is valid because RCC_TypeDef is a struct defined in another header with a member named CR.

Comment: @Bryan Oops, I totally exchanged `offsetof`'s arguments... in that case I am not sure why they did not use default template argument.

Comment: Not sure, might just be for readability in the sense that all the MCU specific memory address are located in one block of code.